# Chat rooms for imported comment threads, no way to sort out

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, chat

I love the new feature, however I have one small problem. If I go to the chat page to see which rooms are available, then I see a mess of "Discussion between N... (cut off)"

Not only do these rooms give no adequate description of what's going on, they've flooded the chat page. There's ~15-18 pages of these things and the real chat rooms are mangled in-between.

I'd like a way to sort out these rooms.

I acknowledge the fact that I can search for rooms, however, what if I'm just browsing and don't know what I really want to do until I see a room that looks good.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yeah, they were kinda causing a flood, and they are generally very specific between two users (maybe three). As such, they are now prioritised *below* the regular rooms - so you should see a bit more of the regular rooms now.